# Elassandra & Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, elassandra

i'm confused with Elassandra and Cassandra ,

How it works actually ?
Is Elassandra & Cassandra serve as separate databases ?
Does an insert(-XPOST) to elassandra also inserts to cassandra table ?
How Elassandra is related to Cassandra ?

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Elassandra is a way to integrate Elastic search with Cassandra, it is based on custom secondary indexes ( in a Cassandra point of view).
When your write data to Cassandra it is indexed automaticly

Each node index it's own data, so it is still master less.

The documentation can give you more details about how it works.
Here is the link

https://elassandra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture.html